# text to speech with php

Tags: php, html, text-to-speech

I want to make a script

text to speech, but it is not in English i recorded audio alphabet

a.mp3, b.mp3, c.mp3.

I created a form with html

```
<form action='read.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='text' size='50'>
<input type='submit' name='go' value='Read!'>
```

but i need code with php where the form convert text to speech

for example i write abc in text input and press Read! so the php will play a.mp3, b.mp3 and c.mp3

after each other

how will the code be ?

and is there any better way to make text to speech web based ??

Comment: Look at [this](http://tts-api.com/) TTS API

Comment: Human speech is more than concatenating alphabetical letters. There are phonems, formants, etc. Use one of the many webservice APIs, or have a look at something like espeak for OSS implementations. Or google “command line TTS”.

Comment: thanks guys, but my language is not listed in intentional languages. so the API's cant be used in my project :(

Comment: Then maybe you should tell us more about your language, or what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok my language is Kurdish and we are using Latin alphabet's :P

Comment: if I record all alphabets and try to play them after each other will that work ?? for example abc ==  a.mp3 b.mp3 c.mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server sided, you cant use PHP to play mp3.
You will need client-sided code to play the sounds (javascript, HTML5, FLASH,..)
All you can do with php is parse the string (exemple: "abcd") and check if
you have "a.mp3, b.mp3, c.mp3, d.mp3" then transmit it via session, or _GET method.
But, it's not the best way as you can use javascript or actionscript code to make the same thing, plus you will need the client-side code to play the sounds in the right order.

Example in pseudo code:

```
<html>
    <script>
         text2speech($string){
             $letters = explode($string);
             foreach($letters as $letter){ play_sound($letter); }
         }
         play_sound($letter){
             $letter."mp3".play();
             while($letter.isPlaying() == true){ /*wait for the sound to finish*/ }
         }
    </script>

    <form>
        <input type="text" name="text2READ"><input type="submit" onlick="text2speech(text2READ.getValue())">
    </form>
</html>
```

Javascript and HTML5 are perfect for what you want to do, you will need to use audio HTML5 tags, and add elements to your DOM with javascript and then call their .play() method using javascript.
The pseudo code i wrote is not completely correct, as you'll need to add audio elements to your DOM etc, i just wrote it so you understand the idea.
Good luck